# Quantlib: Why Interest Rate Swap valuation throwing the 'Runtime error negative time'?

Tags: programming, quantlib, quantitative

```
# Set evaluation date

spotRates = [0.02514, 0.026285, 0.027326299999999998,
         0.0279, 0.029616299999999998, 0.026526,
         0.026028, 0.0258695, 0.025958000000000002,
         0.0261375, 0.026355, 0.0266255,
         0.026898, 0.0271745, 0.02741,
         0.027666, 0.028107000000000004, 0.028412000000000003,
         0.028447, 0.0284165]

spotPeriod = [Period(1, Weeks), Period(1, Months),
          Period(3, Months), Period(6, Months),
          Period(9, Months), Period(1, Years),
          Period(3, Years),Period(5, Years)
          Period(10, Years),Period(15, Years), Period(20, Years),
          Period(30, Years), Period(50, Years)]
```

Comment: Thats not a problem I converted the dates into the formats I required in my program. I valued more than 1000 records but few have given me such error. Am confused why it is so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change a few things because you had 20 spot rates but only 13 spot period, and added a bogus fixing, but here is a working example.

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd

todaysDate = ql.Date(13, 9, 2019)
calendar = ql.SouthAfrica()
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
currency = ql.ZARCurrency()

todaysDate = calendar.adjust(todaysDate)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

spotRates = [0.02514, 0.026285, 0.027326299999999998,
         0.0279, 0.029616299999999998, 0.026526,
         0.026028, 0.0258695, 0.025958000000000002,
         0.0261375, 0.026355, 0.0266255,
         0.026898, 0.0271745, 0.02741,
         0.027666, 0.028107000000000004, 0.028412000000000003,
         0.028447, 0.0284165]

spotPeriod = [ql.Period(1, ql.Weeks), ql.Period(1, ql.Months),
          ql.Period(3, ql.Months), ql.Period(6, ql.Months),
          ql.Period(9, ql.Months), ql.Period(1, ql.Years),
          ql.Period(3, ql.Years),  ql.Period(5, ql.Years),
          ql.Period(10, ql.Years), ql.Period(15, ql.Years), ql.Period(20, ql.Years),
          ql.Period(30, ql.Years), ql.Period(50, ql.Years)]

dates = [calendar.advance(todaysDate, period) for period in spotPeriod]
curve = ql.ZeroCurve(dates, spotRates[:13], day_count, calendar)
yts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(curve)
engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(yts)

issue_date = ql.Date(18, 4, 2018)
maturity_date = ql.Date(18, 4, 2028)
fixedRate = .09
index = ql.Jibar(ql.Period('3M'), yts)
fix_payment_frequency = ql.Annual
float_payment_frequency = ql.Quarterly

fixedSchedule = ql.MakeSchedule(issue_date, maturity_date, ql.Period('1Y'), calendar=calendar)
floatSchedule = ql.MakeSchedule(issue_date, maturity_date, ql.Period('3M'), calendar=calendar)
swap = ql.VanillaSwap(
    ql.VanillaSwap.Payer, 100,
    fixedSchedule, fixedRate, day_count,
    floatSchedule, index, 0, index.dayCounter()
    )

index.addFixing(ql.Date(18,7,2019), 0.02)

swap.setPricingEngine(engine)
data = []
for cf in map(ql.as_coupon, swap.leg(1)):
    if cf.date() > todaysDate:
        data.append({
            'accuralStart': cf.accrualStartDate(),
            'accrualEnd': cf.accrualEndDate(),
            'amount': cf.amount(),
            'rate': cf.rate(),
            'discount': yts.discount(cf.date())

        })
pd.DataFrame(data).head()
```

which would output:

[image]

I suspect you were trying to get a discount factor from a date before the curve date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Very neat answer. Secondly, if my valuation date is 13th sep 2019(as above), are we accounting all cash flows for valuation or any accruals needed to be adjusted separately to get the correct valuation ?